# Is BannerAd.testAdUnitID is out dated?

Tags: flutter, dart, admob, ads, banner-ads

I am following a tutorial of adding a *Banner Ad*. But for me it gives this error.

```
The getter 'testAdUnitID' isn't defined for the type 'BannerAd'.
```

Is `testAdUnitID` is deprecated or something? What's the way out?

My code is:

```
  void _initBannerAd() {
    _bannerAd = BannerAd(
      size: AdSize.banner,
      adUnitId: BannerAd.testAdUnitID,
      listener: BannerAdListener(),
      request: AdRequest(),
    );
  }
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which tutorial did you watch?

#### edit

found update log here.

https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads/changelog

- 2.0.0

  - Removes static testAdUnitId parameters. See the Admob and AdManager documentation for up to date test ad units.

#### solution

you can get some test id for adUnitId from here.

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads

and flutter sample here.

https://developers.google.com/admob/flutter/test-ads

Comment: I was watching this video.

@ video timestamp: 3:00

here is the link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WIp5ATit_d0&t=2s&ab_channel=CodeX

Comment: I still dont understand why testAdUnitID' was error prone. 
However, I got to know that 'adUnitId'  property accepts a string. So, I solved it by giving hard coded string of testing banner ad, e.g. (ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111).
instead of writing BannerAd.testAdUnitId.

Comment: Ok. I found you using google_mobile_ads from your video. And also found removed update log here. https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads/changelog 2.0.0